# How to resolve bad input shape for Multilabel classification

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm, multilabel-classification

I am trying to do multilabel classification with a TfIdfVectorizer transformed data with shape (218,1861) on tags which have the shape of (218,5).

I am getting a

> ValueError: bad input shape (218, 5)

I pass my tags through the function pipeline below:

```
self.q_matrix = tf_idf.fit_transform(question_features)

y = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(tags)

clf.fit(self.q_matrix,y)
```

where `clf` is `LinearSVC`.

Comment: what is the shape of self.q_matrix, and what is the shape of y?

Comment: @MiriamFarber the shape of the self.q_matrix is (218,1861) and the shape of y is (218,5)

Comment: See this example:https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_multilabel.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-multilabel-py

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to fit 5 classifiers (as `y` has 5 columns). You can't do that with `LinearSVC`. As you can see in the documentation of the [fit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.fit) function, your target (`y`) should have just one column:

> y : array-like, shape = [n_samples] Target vector relative to X

So if you would like to fit 5 classifiers (one for each column of `y`), you'll need to fit them separately.